# Does Sweetalert work in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have been copying and pasting code from Sweetalert into Google Tag Manager. It doesn't appear at preview and after submit onto website it doesn't apper. Does Sweetlart works in Google Tag Manager?
(I'm very new to this)

What I did:

1. In custom HTML I put in sweetalert source code as one tag

```html
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

and
triggering: All page view.
Tag firing options: Once per event

2. I put sweeralert pop up script in another tag

```html
   <script>
swal.fire({
 title: "Do you need any consultancy service?",
 text: "Let's",
 type: "info",
 confirmButtonColor: '#000000',
 confirmButtonClass: "contactMeNow_popUpButton",
 confirmButtonText: "Contact Me Now",
 closeOnConfirm: true,
});
</script>
```

with
Tag firing options: Once per event
Tag Sequencing: Sweetalert source code (above)
Triggering: All page load Window load.

3. I have tried combine these two script in one tag but it also doesn't work.

Does sweetalert works with Google Tag Manager? Have I done something wrong in the script or in setting?

Thank you so much for your reply in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the pop up to work on my website.

Comment: Are you following [this tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-create-pop-ups-websites-via-google-tag-manager-u%C4%9Fur-g%C3%BCrsel)? If so, does your code and setup match the one in the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

1. check the console error in `chrome devtool`. There might be some error if this doesn't work.
2. modify the code a bit to check the `swal` is exist

```html
<script>
// try to console this variable is exist or not
console.log(typeof swal)
console.log(swal)

swal.fire({
 title: "Do you need any consultancy service?",
 text: "Let's",
 type: "info",
 confirmButtonColor: '#000000',
 confirmButtonClass: "contactMeNow_popUpButton",
 confirmButtonText: "Contact Me Now",
 closeOnConfirm: true,
});

</script>
```

---

The reason might be even if you fire the js tag earlier. It can not guarantee the second tag will wail the js loading finished by the first tag.

Tag 1 fired ----> Tag 2 fired ----> error

js start loading --------------> it might load finish in here

Answer (score 0):

In your "sweetalert popup tag" tag configuration :
add :
**Tag Sequencing** : Fire a tag before "sweetalert popup tag" fires
and in Setup tag : select your "sweetalert source code tag".

Once you do this the JS code will load before, and your script, which is based on this code, will run correctly.

It runs fine on my website.